# Controlling the positioning for an iframe when using it to source to a react app contained in an iframe

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, web-component

I am looking to present a web component built in react that can be served in static html pages by including it in an iframe. I was wondering if it is possible to define the positioning and size in react to have it carry over. For example if i wanted the iframe tag just dropped in the bottom of the body it will always position it as a button in the top right corner that controls a dropdown.

Comment: Please also post your code snippet so everyone can help you after reviewing it thanks

Comment: No, the container document controls the layout.